# Read Parse.com push payload in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: c#, ios, parse-platform, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I want to read the iOS push "alert" message

parse.com has this example on their website

```
ParsePush.ParsePushNotificationReceived += (sender, args) => {
  var payload = args.Payload;
  object objectId;
  if (payload.TryGetValue("objectId", out objectId)) {
    DisplayRichMessageWithObjectId(objectId as string);
  }
};
```

But how do  I read the alert message from the payload?

**Solution**

```
string message = "";

try
{
    var payload = args.Payload;
        object aps;
        if (payload.TryGetValue("aps", out aps))
        {
            string payloadStr = "";
                try
                {
                    payloadStr = aps.ToString();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                }
                try
                {
                    var match = Regex.Match(payloadStr, @"alert = (.*);\n");
                        if (match.Success)
                        {
                            string alertText = match.Groups[1].Value;
                                message = alertText;
                        }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
ParsePush.ParsePushNotificationReceived += (sender, args) => {
  var payload = args.Payload;
  object aps;
  if (payload.TryGetValue("aps", out aps)) {
    string payloadStr = aps as string;
  }
};
```

Also, there should be a `args.PayloadString` which should give some clues about the structure of the payload.

Comment: args.PayloadString returns null but I can see that args.Payload itself contains aps which contains what I want.
Sadly I can't try this right now but on monday.

Comment: Hi again. This is what it returns http://i.imgur.com/zNeS3qB.png
Do you know any good way of getting the "alert" part out or should I use substrings?

Comment: You need to parse it into a JSON object then you can grab the "alert" value

Comment: But neither the object or the value is proper JSON

Comment: Sorry you're right, looked like JSON at a glance. Maybe use a regex to extract it? Something like: alert = "(.*)"

Comment: Hi again. I used the regex to fix it. I know about the possible issues when the message contains those values